# Command Git rm cached also deletes my file

Tags: git

I have a folder `mpdf` which is **already commited and pushed**, but I want to remove it from the repository.

I added the `mpdf` folder to `.gitignore` and I ran the following command:

```
git rm --cached mpdf
```

It deleted the `mpdf` folder from my working directory, which it shouldn't have done.
What can I do to only remove the folder from the repository and not from the working directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git rm --cached [dir]` should give you a warning :

```
fatal: not removing 'foo' recursively without -r
```

and `git rm --cached -r [dir]` should definitely not delete your local copy of the folder.

---

How can you see that your folder was deleted ? `ls` ?

Are you sure `mpdf` is a folder ? could it be a symlink to some other foler ? (*note* : this still wouldn't explain why the `--cached` command removed your local link)

Comment: @D555 Thanks for accepting my answer ! It was kind of an open answer though, could you please take the time to explain how you actually fixed your problem ?